# Display of specific colors

Tags: r

I am working on color classification. I'm initializing a matrix with a particular color so that I can get a 16x16 matrix of red or blue or green. The code is as follows:

```
 library(rgl)
    color1 <- function()
   {
      n <- 3
      m <- 16
      a <- list("numeric", n)
      wij <- matrix(list(), nrow = m, ncol = m)

      #Initailize the weight matrix
      for(x1 in 1:m)
      {
        for(x2 in 1:m)
        {
          a<-c(1,255,1)
          # a<- c(255,1,1)
          #a<-c(1,1,255)
          wij[[x1,x2]] <- a
          rgl.spheres(x=x1, y=x2, col=wij[[x1,x2]], radius = 1 )
        }
      }
    }    
    color1()
```

For this code, I'm supposed to get a 16x16 matrix of green color, for which I'm getting black color. The same way for the commented lines.
1, 1, 255 I'm getting black instead of blue.
255, 1, 1 I'm getting yellow instead of red.

For two different values (1,1,255 and 1,255,1) I'm getting black color, for which I expected to get blue and green respectively.

I need to specify the values from 0:255, but if I give a zero I get the following error:

> Error in col2rgb(colors) : numerical color values must be positive

So I'm specifying the values from 1:255. Please can anybody help me in getting the required color for a specific value?

Comment: Provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Function `rgl.spheres` is missing in your code.

Comment: Im sorry. I have added that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the last command in your function to:

```
rgl.spheres(x=x1, y=x2, col=rgb(t(wij[[x1,x2]]), maxColorValue = 255), radius = 1 )
```

**Explanation:**
Colors in R are specified as a character string corresponding to pre-defined colors (`colors()`) or to hexadecimal RGB encoding "#RRGGBB". Specifying a number in the `col=` argument will return a color from a palette.

```
cols <- function(a) image(1:5, 1, as.matrix(1:5), col=a, axes=FALSE , xlab="", ylab="")
a <- 1:5
cols(a)
```

[image]

Color number 255 is yellow. In your function, RGB values `c(1, 255, 1)` are interpreted as `c("black", "yellow", "black")`.

```
a <- c(1, 255, 1); cols(a)
```

[image]

We thus need to create R colors from their RGB intensities, using the `rgb()` function. The function accepts a matrix of the three intensities. A vector is coerced into a matrix with R default, which fills data by columns. We need a row of intensities, and the easiest way out is transposing the matrix.

```
a <- rgb(t(a), maxColorValue = 255)
a
[1] "#01FF01"
cols(a)
```

[image]

In this way, you can also use zeros.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves the problem for you (the check mark at the left). http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers